# Problem with implementing the CSS breakpoint mixin using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mixins

Based on https://tobbelindstrom.com/blog/how-to-create-a-breakpoint-mixin-with-styled-components/  I'm trying to do the same thing in TypeScript but I'm failing to type this function.

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';
import { breakpoints } from './_variables';

export const respondTo = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce(
  (accumulator, label) => {
    accumulator[label] = (...args) => css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}) {
        ${css(...args)};
      }
    `;
    return accumulator;
  },
  {}
);
```

I tried something like this:

```
export const respondTo = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce<Record<string, Function>>(
  (accumulator, label) => {
    accumulator[label] = (...args: Array<String>) => css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}) {
        ${css(...args)};
      }
    `;
    return accumulator;
  },
  {}
);
```

but it keeps throwing errors. Right now, it gives me

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.  TS7053
```

at `breakpoints[label]`.

Comment: Please revise your title to ask an actual question and not just list tags.

Comment: typescript thinks `breakpoints` is an empty object. What is the expected type of `breakpoints` and how is that defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

const breakpoints = {
  xs: "480px",
  sm: "768px",
  md: "992px",
  lg: "1200px"
};

type cssParams = Parameters<typeof css>;
const keys = Object.keys(breakpoints) as Array<keyof typeof breakpoints>;

export const respondTo = keys.reduce((accumulator, label) => {
  accumulator[label] = (...args: cssParams) => {
    return css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}) {
        ${css(...args)};
      }
    `;
  };
  return accumulator;
}, {} as Record<keyof typeof breakpoints, Function>);
```

The problem was `breakpoints[label]`: `Object.keys()` returns type `string[]`, so `label` becomes `string`, which is not a valid key of `breakpoints`.

Alternatively you could re-type your `breakpoints` to something like `Record<string, string>`.

I also added `cssParams`, which would get you after solving this issue ;)

Comment: Thx for the answer but it did not change anything ;(

Comment: Oh... I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: Updated the answer (I guess you don't get notified...)

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. Your solution works great. Thanks for that :) I have a question regarding one line `type cssParams = Parameters<typeof css>;
` Why do we need that ?

Comment: No problem on that, glad it works for you. You could inline it or solve it otherwise, but if you use `(...args: Array<String>)` TS will complain `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more. ts(2557)`, because `args` could be an empty array and `css` expects at least on parameter.

Comment: Thanks for help :) I marked Your answer as the correct one. Have a nice day